# Main class block in '{}' never executes

Tags: java, puzzle

Consider the following code:-

```
class Name {

    {System.out.println("hi");}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(waffle());
    }

    static boolean waffle() {
        try {
            return true;
        } finally {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This never outputs "hi" . Why is this?

Comment: Why would you expect it to execute?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The code in the braces is the [instance initializer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6).

From [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), [Section 8.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6):

> An instance initializer declared in a
>   class is executed when an instance of
>   the class is created (§15.9), as
>   specified in §8.8.5.1.

If the `Name` class is executed, the `public static void main(String[])` method is called by the Java virtual machine, but the `Name` class is not is not instantiated, so the code in the instance initializer will never be executed.

There is also a [static initializer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7), which is similar in appearance to the instance initializer, but it has the `static` keyword in front:

```
static {
    // Executed when a class is first accessed.
}
```

Again, from [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), [Section 8.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7):

> Any static initializers declared in a
>   class are executed when the class is
>   initialized and, together with any
>   field initializers (§8.3.2) for class
>   variables, may be used to initialize
>   the class variables of the class
>   (§12.4).

The [Initializing Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) page from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) also has information about the static and instance initializer blocks.

Comment: Well answered, very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is activated only on instance creation. Try running it as static { ... }

Answer (score 1):

The block should be declared static to get it to run, i.e. static{System.out.println("hi");}